# Online-Only iCloud Key Storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud

The app I'm developing has consumable in-app purchase currency that can be used to unlock content.

I'm currently tracking/backing-up the level of 'credits' via iCloud KVC. However, if a user was to unlock items on another, offline device, then the credits wouldn't update on the online device and vice-versa (as outlined by Apple in their iCloud Design Guide). This is solvable for things like high-scores, but for purchasable currency, I think an online-verification approach would work.

Is there a way to force a check against iCloud for the most recent key-value pair? I.e. if the device was offline it would just return an error, and if it were online it would update the total accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` should return nil if your asking for any object before it got the chance to sync with the cloud. You can build a mechanism to handle such a case or otherwise use the data you have (if it was successfully obtained online).